# can Oauth2 server be used as a custom oauth provider using HWIOauthBUndle in symfony2

Tags: symfony, drupal-7, oauth-2.0

In HWioauth Bundle we must provide infos_url but drupal doesn't seems to have such api url, and all said oauth2 require ssl. Is it neccessarily required that my app doesn't seem to get authorization_code from the oauth server(drupal site as a oauth server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's necessary for production environment. Because OAuth 2.0 use the client_id, secret_id and passwords in request URL as query variables.

But if you are using it development mode in your computer it will work. Https not a requirement for OAuth logic, it's about only security.